# WCF - Big response takes very long between being returned by my code and being sent to the client while having 100% CPU usage

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, nettcpbinding

The situation is like this:

- I have a WCF host with a duplex nettcpbinding
- I have a WCF client that asks for an object which contains a byte array (an image of approximately 2MB)
- I get this object (server side) using the entity framework from my database and it is something like this:

  - id (int)
  - type (string)
  - data (byte[] of approx 2MB)
- I then return it to the client (actually to the .NET wcf code, where it should get serialized and then sent to the client), and from then on I can't debug any further and my code seems to have returned fine in the server, but my client keeps waiting for 15 seconds or more until it gets a reply from the service host. 
  My cpu uses 100% of a core (used by the application that hosts the service), so it's busy with doing something between my return and sending it. I'm sure it's not the sending that's taking so long, because my reliable session starts to ask for retransmissions, since it's not receiving anything, making it even worse... So i turned off the reliable session, what caused the service only having to reply once to my request :), but 15 bloody seconds for 2MB of data...

When i have no data (so null for the data part), it works fine. The larger the image gets, the longer it takes... And the strangest thing is that it sometimes goes very fast (1 second or something like that (but that doesn't happen much and it seems to be random). This happens on all computers I've tested, so nothing to do with my PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you reproduce it locally?

If so, I would suggest using asp.net mini profiler. I would use it on every single page, even ones that don't have obvious performance issues.

http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/

I found a nice article on it too;
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek9ASPNETMiniProfilerFromStackExchangeRocksYourWorld.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I might have forgotten to mention that this is a self-hosted WCF service, not ASP.NET. So I guess that this tool can't be used for this case?

Comment: ah okay, you are correct, that profiler is not really suitable for WCF. However, WCF fortunately has terrific logging. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702726.aspx

Comment: OMG... this brought me to the solution :-). I already turned on the logging for debugging purposes (which I used to try to find the solution for this problem). When I turn the logging off, everything is suddenly fast, probably because the logger doesn't need to serialize and write a lot of data to the disk anymore. Thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 0):

So the 100% CPU is on the server side, correct?

You could sprinkle some of these in your WCF code to see if you can narrow down the line of code causing the issue.

```
DateTime Start = DateTime.Now;
DateTime End = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan CallTime = End - Start;
Console.WriteLine("Call Time(MS): " + CallTime.Milliseconds.ToString());
```

Not seeing any code, I would guess it is the Serialize method of your database object. You could implement a custom serialization interface since you are really just interested in sending the byte[].

Comment: Hi. I tried to do this to identify the code (but with StopWatch class, but that is a detail :) ), but I can't seem to measure anything on the server, since it doesn't seem to happen in my code. It happens after I return my object to the client. I already tried to just return a string with the image in base64 encoding and also just a byte[], but that takes just as long (again nowhere in my code)...